# Stash Get_List outputting additional empty item

Tags: stash, parse-order

I have a client that needs a slider that can either show text, or a "tweet" (using CE Tweet for getting the tweet's info). I'm using Stash, and thought this would be the best way to get there:

```
    {exp:channel:entries
        channel='slides'
        dynamic='no'
    }
        {exp:stash:set_list 
            name='home_slides' 
            parse_tags='yes'
            parse_depth='2'
        }
            {if slide_type == 'tweet'}
                {slide_tweet type='show'}
                    {stash:list_text}{text}{/stash:list_text}
                    {stash:list_attribution}{user_name}, <a href="https://twitter.com/{user_screen_name}" target="_blank">{user_screen_name}</a>{/stash:list_attribution}
                    {stash:list_cta}<span class="ui-retweet"></span> Retweet{/stash:list_cta}
                    {stash:list_link}https://twitter.com/intent/retweet?tweet_id={id_str}{/stash:list_link}
                {/slide_tweet}
            {if:else}
                {stash:list_text}{slide_text}{/stash:list_text}
                {stash:list_attribution}{slide_source}{/stash:list_attribution}
                {stash:list_cta}{slide_call_to_action}{/stash:list_cta}
                {stash:list_link}{slide_link}{/stash:list_link}
            {/if}
        {/exp:stash:set_list}
    {/exp:channel:entries}
```

This is where I'm outputting the list (simplified slightly):

```
    {exp:channel:entries
    channel='pages'
    limit='1'
    require_entry='yes'
}
    {exp:stash:set parse_tags='yes'}
        {stash:page_title}{title}{/stash:page_title}
        {stash:page_content}
            <section class="slider">
                <ul data-orbit data-options="bullets: false; ">
                    {exp:stash:get_list name='home_slides' prefix='list'}
                        <!-- {list:count} -->
                        <li>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="large-12 columns">
                                    <h2><span class="ui-quote"><span class="ui-quote-open"></span></span>
                                        {list_text}<br>
                                        <small class="attribution">{list_attribution}</small>
                                    </h2>
                                    <p><a href="{list_link}" class="btn">{list_cta}</a></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    {/exp:stash:get_list}
                </ul>
            </section>
        {/stash:page_content}
    {/exp:stash:set}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Now after my actual entry gets outputted, another "slide" gets put into my template, but all the stash-variables in that list-item are empty. Any idea as to where this emtpy item might come from?

Thanks!

- Steven

Answer (score 1):

You're re-wrapping your Stash get_list in another Channel Entries tag pair where you're also outputting 1. `limit="1"`. So it looks like it will probably be running the Stash list and then acting on the outer loop of the extra Channel Entries tag pair.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so apparently this is an enormous conflict between `stash:set_list`, switchee and parse-order. The parse order doesn't play nice with the combination of set_list and switchee, so I refactored it to plain conditionals, causing the unmatched conditional to parse but not return anything, fooling stash into thinking there's another item. Has anyone experienced this before?